# Chain Dot Net 4 Framework install into NSIS

Tags: .net-4.0, installation, nsis

I am trying to silently install the .NET 4 Framework with my app through NSIS.

I cant for the life of me work out how to make the .NET installer report where its up to back to my installer and update the progress bar on NSIS to reflect this.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit: Just to clarify I want to do this as when the .NET installer runs silently it looks like my installer has frozen as the progress bar does not move until .NET is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by any setup tool. Third-party installer progress cannot be captured and integrated into a main installer.

Instead, the third-party installation (.NET Framework) can run with basic progress. This way it shows it's own progress bar which is more accurate than what you could capture in a main installer.

Comment: Well this is a tutorial for getting information from the .Net installer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859983.aspx it just seemed a bit heavy handed. Any idea how to use that information with NSIS? Its using named pipes to communicate.

Comment: @Hellfire It is not using pipes, it uses a section (memory map), you would have to write a custom NSIS plugin to interface with that "API"

Comment: Oh sorry I though a Named Pipe in windows was the same thing? Will look into custom plugin, thanks Anders :)